# Want to convert format time to minutes

Tags: php, datetime-format

I have used date() and mktime() functions to convert minutes to proper time format like H:i now I waned to convert back H:i to minutes form I tried to used some mathematical calculation but it is not working though when I update and check back it is not giving me that time which I had updated in the time field I selected time 11:11 AM and when I updated it shows me time as 02:01 AM as it should have shown me same time see what I did here is

Updating time and storing time in database as in integer value by converting time to minutes here is what I did

```
    $st_time    = explode(':', $_POST['start_time']);
    if($st_time[1] == '00') {
        $start_time = $st_time[0] * 60;
    } else {
        $start_time = $st_time[0] * $st_time[1];
    }
```

For retrieving back from the database I used some php built in function

```
<input type="time" class="form-control" name="start_time" value="<?php echo date('H:i', mktime(0,$data['start_time'])); ?>" />
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong what thing is that I am missing??

Comment: The thing you are missing is PHP's built in [DateTime classes](http://PHP.net/DateTime).

Comment: why do you explode the time and dont just extract the minutes with a DateTime built in function ? try this: `$date = strtotime($_POST['start_time']);
echo date('H', $date);` and it will give you the Hours.

Comment: I want to save time in minutes format so the given method will work it will convert time that would be 12:00 converted to minutes ?

Comment: @vascowhite yes I want to use it but I am unable to recall how do i use it

Comment: Read the manual in the link i gave you.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the custome time you set up there you can pass the `mktime` as argument for `getdate(...)` , so that :

```
$time =mktime(3,12,0,1,25,1995);
$getTime =getdate($time);

$monthday =$getTime["mday"];  
$weekday = $getTime["mon"];  
$year = $getTime["year"];
$h = $getTime["hours"];
$m = $getTime["minutes"];
$s = $wkt["seconds"];
```

Or, even *strtotime*

```
   $time = strtotime("25 January 1992 3:12pm");
     $getTime = getdate($time );
    $h = $getTime["hours"];
    $m = $getTime["minutes"];
    $s = $wkt["seconds"];
```

Or if it's current time instead then:

```
$currentTime = getdate();

$t = $currentTime["hours"];
$m = $currentTime["minutes"];
$s = $currentTime["seconds"];
```

So you just can simplify your custome date operation

Comment: I only need minutes to be saved in db